# How to avoid code duplication when writing DoStuff() and DoStuffAsync() method variants?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I often find that I need to write a lot of code for synchronous and asynchronous method implementations when writing library functions. Is there a way to avoid it without much overhead? Like for example implement only async version and then wrap it in such a way that it executes synchronously on current thread.

Answer (score 2):

I have [an article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

My favorite approach - if sync and async are **both *required*** - is the boolean argument hack. That is, the "core" method takes a `bool sync` argument, and if it's true, then it guarantees that it returns an already-completed task.

Answer (score 0):

If your library targets multiple framework versions, it's better to keep both async and non-async version because of pre-NET45 versions.

If the above is not a concern, you should keep the async version. The caller should be implemented as async all the way through. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

You need to identify what is common, and put that into a method that multiple public members can use. But what is common will depend on what you're working on.

For example if I have a complex EF query that I want to use both synchronously and asynchronously:

```
public IList<TResult> GetStuff(string selector) {
  return GetStuffCore(selector).ToList();
}

public async Task<IList<TResult>> GetStuffAsync(string selector) {
  return await GetStuffCore(selector).ToListAsync();
}

private IQueryable<TResult> GetStuffCore(string selector)
  return from s in ctx.Stuff
         where s.Thing.Contains(selector)
         // lots of LINQ
         select some-complex expression;
}
```

However this simple approach would not suit cases where there are multiple operations that are potentially awaitable.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep single responsibility on classes/interfaces, e.g.:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Task<IBar> DoStuffAsync(string optionalArg, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public static class IFooExtensions
{
    public static IBar DoStuff(this IFoo foo, string optionalArg)
        => foo.DoStuffAsync(optionalArg, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

This keeps class/interface clear meaning that only async version of a method is supported and actually needed, where sync version of a method is just an extensibility (helper).

The same applies to overloaded methods with optional arguments:

```
public static class IFooExtensions
{
    public static Task<IBar> DoStuffAsync(this IFoo foo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => foo.DoStuffAsync(optionalArg: "defaultValue", cancellationToken);
}
```

This helps a lot when you have multiple implementations of the same interface or abstract/base class, and very easy to use in tests when you need mocks, because you are not confused which overloaded methods you need to mock out.